# Boton de menu responsivo no muestra icono deseado. Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy agregando un menú dinámico para cuando este en un dispositivo pequeño me aparezca un botón que despliegue las opciones. El problema es que no me aparece el icono que escogí en los componentes bootstrap **glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger** solamente me aparece un pequeño cuadrito.
Al escoger un componente relativamente mas pequeño si me aparece bien.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
<header class="container">
  <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger "></span>
      </button>          
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav active"><a href=".">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="contact.html">Story</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="contact.html">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: que versión de bootstrap usas?

Comment: Estoy usando la 3.0 porque si uso la actual no se me despliegan las opciones

Comment: Es por los colores que utilizas, fijate de cambiarlos, probando tu mismo código pero con la barra inversa se ve perfecto, podrías cambiarle el color vía css. http://www.bootply.com/tbNqRswdYp

Comment: Si no se despliega el menú deberías chequear la referencia al .js de bootstrap tambien a jquery.

Comment: En efecto es por la versión de bootstrap, la cambie a la actual y corregi mi referencia jquery

Comment: Perfecto, si es la solución puedes agregar una respuesta y marcarla como correcta! así le puede servir a otro usuario con tu mismo problema.

Comment: Elimina el cache y pasate a la ultima version de bootstraps

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entendí de tu problema fue que el icono menu-hamburger no te parece, cierto?
de ser así, yo probé tu código y si me aparece, puede ser el color de la fuente que se pierde con el color del botón, prueba cambiándolo!

Comment: Intentaste deplegar las opciones?? Me parece que es problema de la versión de bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

**La Solución es simple:**
**1)** Asegurate de que el tamaño de la fuente es el indicado.
**2)** Asegurate de que el color de la fuente no es del mismo color que el fondo del elemento padre que lo arropa.
**3)** Si ninunga de las opciones anteriores te ha funcionado, cambiate a FontAwesome, personalmente posee mejor vectorización de iconos y más variedad. El link de la página es el siguiente: http://fontawesome.io/
**4)** Como ultima recomendación comienza tu aprendizaje de diseño básico en illustrator en Windows y Corel Draw en Centos y diseña tus propios iconos.